# Spring Integration 5.0 Reactor types support

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, project-reactor

From release notes (https://spring.io/blog/2017/11/29/spring-integration-5-0-ga-available):

> - Reactive Streams support via FluxMessageChannel,
>     ReactiveStreamsConsumer and direct org.reactivestreams.Subscriber
>     implementation in the AbstractMessageHandler;

My understanding for Reactor support was e.g. you can return Mono/Flux from a transformer/handler, and Spring Integration will automatically transform it to Messages while respecting back pressure. Unfortunately, I cannot make it work like that, e.g.:

```
IntegrationFlows.from("input")
                .handle((p, h) -> Flux.just(1, 2, 3))
                .log("l1")
                .channel("output")
                .get();
```

still logs one Message with FluxArray typed payload instead of three Messages with Integer payloads.

```
2017-12-18 17:12:33.262  INFO 97471 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] l1 : GenericMessage [payload=FluxArray, headers={id=a9701681-9945-f953-8b72-df369c2982a3, timestamp=1513613553262}]
```

Also, there is nothing in docs according this behaviour and new

> FluxMessageChannel,
>   ReactiveStreamsConsumer and direct org.reactivestreams.Subscriber
>   implementation in the AbstractMessageHandler

So my question is, do I understand implemented Reactor support correctly, and where can I find any info on that topic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since we here in messaging and that really doesn't matter for the message what kind of payload you return from your service, everything is just wrapped to the `Message` as is. You need a special component to understand this payload. One of them is `Splitter`. This one determines that your payload is a Reactive Streams `Publisher` and iterated over that as a `Flux`.

Another component is `WebFluxInboundEndpoint` which supports this kind of payloads natively.

Your custom Service Activator might expect `Flux` as an argument to deal with.

But nothing happens automatically. Spring Integration supports Reactive types, but doesn't do they processing without end-user preferences.

BTW, the `splitter` should be supplied with the `FluxMessageChannel` as an output to process the splitted `Flux` via back--pressure manner.

Feel free to raise A JIRA about documenting `FluxMessageChannel`. Indeed we have missed that. The `ReactiveStreamsConsumer` needs more love as well and we have some plans for `5.1` to improve Reactive Streams model and we'll try to make it more flexible or even like an option to turn on it by default. Nothing can promise from today though.